# Changing hubs on wheel

Tags: wheels, through-axle

I just picked up a Manitou Tower pro fork to replace the Suntour XCT and it's a 15mm thru-axle wheel mount, which means that I need to replace the hub on my wheel since it's a 9mm QR.

I am unsure of how to approach actually swapping the hub/spokes. I've been looking online and a DT Swiss XR2.5 hub + spokes combo popped up. I have a Kona Mahuna 2013 and all that's on there currently is the original Formula hub and spokes. Is there any thing that would prevent me from simply changing the hub + spokes with the XR2.5 hub?

This is the front tire/hub also.

Sorry if it's a little convoluted, I've never messed with wheels before.

Comment: Given that the bike is a 800 dollar MSRP bike, if there isn't a conversion kit for the hub to take the thru axle (check with your LBS), you're likely better off just buying a whole new wheel rather than reusing the rim with a new hub, from a cost perspective.

Comment: If you want to try rebuilding the wheel, have at it.  It's an "interesting" job.  You need a truing stand, a *good* spoke wrench, and a book with a good section on wheel building.  Some folks also recommend a spoke tension meter, but that's not required.  If you're going to pay someone else to rebuild, though, it's probably just a cheap to buy a new wheel.

Comment: You don't need a truing stand, masking tape across the two legs will give you a radial reference and you can mark a lateral reference using a pen. A zip tie on one leg can also be used.

Comment: But in this case I would just replace the wheel.

Comment: If you are building a wheel for the first time it probably takes around a day or at least a full afternoon to do it properly. If you are very talented you might be faster ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Swapping the hub and spokes is possible, but be aware it is a very involved process.  The spokes need to be the right size for the new hub/rim combo, and there are about 200 sizes of spokes, in 1mm increments.  More often than not, it's more cost and time effective to buy a new wheel, but if you're dead set on doing it yourself, you will want to do a spoke length calculation on the new setup, there are a few places online that may be able to help some, but the best ones are services you have to pay for.  You will want a good spoke wrench, a truing stand can come in useful, and lots of patience is a must.